# Mayim shelanu history?

Tags: halacha, passover, water, matzah

The water used to bake Matzah must be mayim shelanu—water that had been drawn in the evening and left to cool overnight. What is the halachic background for this requirement?

Comment: If you'd [edit] in what you know already (e.g. where this is in _Shulchan Aruch_), it'd help others trace the history back for you.

Comment: See פסחים נב עמוד א׳ ושם צב עמוד ב.

Comment: In pesachim 42a, rav yehudah makes the statement that water for matzah making must be “mayim shelanu” – waters that slept (undser vaser). This indicates that the water should have been drawn from the day before, and left to rest overnight, before use, though the exact number of hours it needs to be in vessels and such is subject to some discussion.

Comment: The goal is to allow the water in underground springs (which was thought to be heated at night by the sun as during that time the sun was not heating from above as per an explanation on pesachim 94b) to cool sufficiently so that it does not hasten the leavening (this matches with the next drasha on the daf – that a woman should not knead dough in the sun or with warm water). The gemara gives no other source for this halacha, and those who codify it, don’t seem to tie it to a posuk or other origin

Comment: The rambam brings down this halacha in hilchot chametz u’matzah 5:11 and this is discussed in the mishna berurah, 455, se’ifim 1 through 4.

Comment: @Danno, I don't really know Yiddish, but isn't "undser" the translation of English "our" (the _other_ "shelanu")?

Comment: @msh210 I have seen it called that. I know no Yiddish, but that would make it related to the story of Rav Matya in Papunya.

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org.il/Pesachim.42a.8?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Punctuated_Aramaic&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Answer (score 0):

This halacha is brought down in the Shulchan Aruch 455 where the Mishna Beura explains what it is according to Rashi. Where R ashi explains that in Nissan spring water is hot as the sun heats up the springs (as the location of the sun in that time is close to the earth's ground). There is also another opinion who understands differently to Rashi, how the sun heats the springs up.  With regards to making Matzah one is not allowed to use hot water as it will be easy to make it chametzdik. Therefore the Rabbis said one must leave this hot water in a vessel overnight to cool it down.

Comment: What if you're baking the matza months in advance of Nissan (as many modern bakeries do)?

Comment: @DoubleAA overnight equals 12 hours. There's no difference between shorter or longer nights due to "לא פלוג." https://www.sefaria.org/Machatzit_HaShekel_on_Orach_Chayim.455.1.7. Though there are some who are lenient.