# Maharil and Terumat haDeshen: Mayim Shelanu

Tags: halacha, ashkenazi, water, matzah, machlokes

Inspired by [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/70254/mayim-shelanu-history).

I have heard a machloket in the names of the Maharil and the Terumat haDeshen about the source for mayim shelanu. While the details were given, the sources were not.

The machloket itself is whether mayim shelanu must be drawn by a Jew or not (שלנו may be read as German "unser" or *our*). The Maharil (Minhag Rheinus) is said to bring that only Jews should draw it (presumably darshening from the word שלנו) whereas the Terumat haDeshen brings that anyone may draw it (Minhag Österreich).

Where are these particular opinions brought?

---

I recall hearing that these opinions are summarised in a sefer called אוצר הגדולים on a daf in the 90s. I have no way to verify, as the copy I've seen was barely legible.

Comment: It's a Gemara in Pesachim

Comment: kitzur (siman 109, se’if 5) as background